# How to profile outlier requests in golang

Tags: performance, go, profiler

I'm quite new to profiling in go, and I'm a little stuck.

I'm building a server that processes events in realtime. This component of the system has a latency budget of around 2ms. On average, it's beating that by some margin.

90% of requests have sub-millisecond latency, as measured by `wrk`. However, in a sufficiently large batch of requests a few will be outliers, spiking as slow as +20ms

---

My issue is I need to profile this to understand what is causing the spike, but I don't know how to capture a profile *just* for outlier events. Instead I get results that are combined across all of them.

Given the average latency is so small and I have to run thousands of requests to get a spike, I can't use this to diagnose the problem.

Is there any way to capture *only* the relevant data? I'm open to anything really, third party libs, totally different approaches, even potentially paid services (though I've used some and the telemetry was insufficient to be useful for this)